# How to Make Gosu Ruby Basic Shapes

Tags: ruby, libgosu

I am trying to make some simple shapes in gosu (ruby). I am finding it difficult where to call the functions. Is it update method or the draw method.

```
   require 'rubygems'
   require 'gosu'

     class DemoWindow < Gosu::Window
        def initialize
          super(640, 400, false)
        end

        def draw
           draw_quad(x-size, y-size, 0xffffffff, x+size, y-size, 0xffffffff, x-size, y+size, 0xffffffff, x+size, y+size, 0xffffffff, 0)
           draw_triangle(x1, y1, c1, x2, y2, c2, x3, y3, c3, z=0, mode=:default)
           draw_line(x1, y1, c1, x2, y2, c2, z=0, mode=:default)

     end
   end
```

Please take a look and let me know if this is the right way to create shapes.

Comment: yes, you can draw primitives in gosu this way, in the draw method. i would suggest to set all attributes like colors, images etc. in the initialize method. do you have some concrete issues ?

Answer (score 2):

From what I'm seeing what you've got should work.

One thing I've noticed about Gosu is that when it first starts up it calls the draw method before it calls the update function. What that means is if you have (not including the shape functions you're using) any images you are going to draw to the screen that you only have defined coordinates for in the update method the program won't work. You've got to define their x and y values with some preliminary location in the draw method first.

This probably won't help you but I thought I'd contribute it on the off chance it might.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have noticed that you do not have update method therefore it is not rendering

```
 class DemoWindow < Gosu::Window
    def initialize
      super(640, 400, false)
    end

    def update
    end

    def draw
       draw_quad(x-size, y-size, 0xffffffff, x+size, y-size, 0xffffffff, x-size, y+size, 0xffffffff, x+size, y+size, 0xffffffff, 0)
       draw_triangle(x1, y1, c1, x2, y2, c2, x3, y3, c3, z=0, mode=:default)
       draw_line(x1, y1, c1, x2, y2, c2, z=0, mode=:default)

 end
```